# Loss does not change during training of my model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to predict a time series using cnn-lstm model.This is my model:

```
def generate_model():
 model = keras.models.Sequential([

  Conv1D(64, 3, padding='causal', activation='relu', input_shape=(24, 20)),
  BatchNormalization(),
  Conv1D(64, 3, padding='causal', activation='relu'),
  BatchNormalization(),
  Conv1D(32, 3, padding='causal', activation='relu'),
  MaxPool1D(3),
  LSTM(100, dropout=0.2, return_sequences=True),
  LSTM(50, dropout=0.3),
  Dense(1, activation='relu')
 ])

 model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
            loss='mean_squared_error',
            metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.MeanAbsoluteError(),  tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError(), RSquare()])

  return model
```

Then I use this line of code to train my model:

```
history1 = model1.fit(X1_train, y1_train, epochs=200, batch_size=32, validation_data=(X1_test, y1_test), verbose=2, callbacks=callbacks)
```

But values of loss and metrics stays the same and does not change. This is how they look. [image]

These are my callbacks, just in case:

```
from keras.callbacks import LearningRateScheduler

def decay_schedule(epoch, lr):

lr = lr - 0.0001
return lr

lr_scheduler = LearningRateScheduler(decay_schedule)

callback = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='max', min_delta=1e-3, patience=50)

callbacks=[lr_scheduler, callback]
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi Navid  It looks like you're doing regression, are you sure you want to do `relu` activation in the final Dense layer? That's going to constrain your outputs to be greater than 0, which may not be correct.

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for your response. I am actually trying to implement the cnn-lstm model from this article [link](https://journalofbigdata.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/s40537-021-00548-1). Targets are all positive values. So I guess relu would be fine.